# Replace the content of an RwLockWriteGuard

Tags: rust

Let's assume the following code:

```
use std::sync::RwLock;

pub struct NotCloneable(u8);

pub struct Foo {
    value: RwLock<Vec<NotCloneable>>,
}

impl Foo {
    // does not work
    pub fn filter_out_values(&self) {
        let mut guard = self.value.write().unwrap();
        *guard = guard.into_iter().filter(|nc| nc.0 != 0).collect();
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:12:18
   |
12 |         *guard = guard.into_iter().filter(|nc| nc.0 != 0).collect();
   |                  ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=36e4a1dcbf5e86cd345038e7b0946c0d))

How do I make the function `filter_out_values` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The special circumstance here is, that your `T` is not Cloneable, therefore you cannot use `guard.iter().filter(...).cloned().collect()`.

I see two options here.

1. Instead of `RwLock<Vec<NotCloneable>>` you could use `RwLock<Option<Vec<NotCloneable>>>` and then use [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to get the value the `RwLock` was holding and leaving `None`
2. You could use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), which is a shortcut for [`std::mem::replace(v, Default::default())`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html), to get the `vec` from the guard without triggering the error, because there is no way that you leave the value of the RwLock in an undefined state, where it does not hold any value

```rust
use std::sync::RwLock;

pub struct NotCloneable(u8);

pub struct Foo {
    value: RwLock<Vec<NotCloneable>>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn filter_out_values(&self) {
        let mut guard = self.value.write().unwrap();
        let vec = std::mem::take(&mut *guard);
        *guard = vec.into_iter().filter(|nc| nc.0 != 0).collect();
    }
}

pub struct Foo1 {
    value: RwLock<Option<Vec<NotCloneable>>>,
}

impl Foo1 {
    pub fn filter_out_values(&self) {
        let mut guard = self.value.write().unwrap();
        let vec = guard.take();
        *guard = Some(vec.unwrap().into_iter().filter(|nc| nc.0 != 0).collect());
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1740694e33db8666a6be01a9e22c9036))

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by laying down guidelines for when to use either alternatives: use `replace` if you can and `Option<_>` if you must. With the difference being that when the `T` in `RwLock<T>` can be cheaply built (like an empty `Vec`), then is better for ease of use to avoid the superfluous layer of wrapping, but otherwise a slightly more awkward ease of use might be worth the performance gain.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer is correct, in this case, I'd recommend you to use [`Vec::retain()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain):

```rust
impl Foo {
    pub fn filter_out_values(&self) {
        let mut guard = self.value.write().unwrap();
        guard.retain(|nc| nc.0 != 0);
    }
}
```

It will also be faster.